# Existence of two subspaces in vector space $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional complex vector spaces and let $f: V\xrightarrow[]{}W$ and $g: W\xrightarrow[]{}V$ be linear maps. Suppose that $f(g(w))=w$ holds for any $w\in W$. Show that there exist subspaces $V_0, V_1$ of $V$ that satisfy all of the following three conditions.

1. $V= V_0 \oplus V_1$ that is $V$ is the direct sum of $V_0$ and $V_1$
2. For any $v\in V_0$, $g(f(v))=0$
3. For any $v\in V_1$, $g(f(v))=v$

I tried to think so much to prove the existence but could not get a good idea, here we need to prove the existence of these two subspaces $V_0$ and $V_1$. Does that mean we need to check the three conditions(not empty, closure under addition and scalar multiplication) only? How do we use the given conditions to prove that.

I know from 1 - $V_0 \cap V_1 = \{0\}$

How do we contribute all the things? I would appreciate if anyone could show me the right path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V_1=\ker f$ and let $V_0=g(W)$.

1. If $v\in V_1\cap V_0$, then $v=g(w)$ for some $w\in W$ and $f(v)=0$. But$$0=f(v)=f\bigl(g(w)\bigr)=w$$and therefore $v=g(w)=0$. On the other hand, if $v\in V$, then $v=v-g\bigl(f(v)\bigr)+g\bigl(f(v)\bigr)$. Clearly, $g\bigl(f(v)\bigr)\in V_1$. Furthrmore, $f\left(v-g\bigl(f(v)\bigr)\right)=f(v)-f(v)=0$, and therefore $V=V_0\bigoplus V_1$.
2. If $v\in V_0$, $f(v)=0$ and therefore $g\bigl(f(v)\bigr)=0$.
3. If $v\in V_1$, $v=g(w)$ for some $w\in W$ and therefore$$g\left(f\bigl(v)\right)=g\left(f\bigl(g(w)\bigr)\right)=g(w)=v.$$

Comment: We need to show the existence of $V_0$ and $V_1$, is this sufficient?

Comment: What do you mean? I *defined* $V_1$ as $\ker f$ and $V_0$ as $g(W)$. What more do you think that is needed?

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner I thought we need to show that the three conditions for $V_0$ and $V_1$

Comment: *Which* three conditions?

Comment: not empty, closure under addition and scalar multiplication

Comment: Those three conditions *always* hold for kernels and images of linear maps.

Comment: yes I got it, thank you very much

Comment: sorry for bothering, why do you take $V_1 = \ker f$ and $V_0=g(W)$, here $V_0=g(W)$ is $\ker g$?

Comment: Why are you saying that $V_0=\ker g$. It is not. It is the *image* of $g$.

Comment: Yes I got that, could you please tell me what is the reason to take $V_1$ as kernal of $f$ and $V_0$ as image of $g(W)$, since less of the practice I didn't see it.

Comment: If $v\in\ker f$, then $f(v)=0$ and therefore $g\bigl(f(v)\bigr)=0$. That's how I got the idea of taking $V_1=\ker f$. And if $v\in V_1$, then, since $v=g\bigl(f(v)\bigr)$, $v\in g(W)$. That's how I got the idea of taking $V_0=g(W)$.

Comment: If $v\in \ker f$ then $f(v)=0$ is ok but then $g(f(v))= g(0)$ why this equals $0$, if it is $g(f(v))=0$ is in $V_0$, isn't it?

Comment: If $f(v)=0$, then $g\bigl(f(v)\bigr)=g(0)=0$. The equality $g(0)=0$ holds for any linear map.

Answer (score 1):

We have that  $fg= id_W$. Now show that $(gf)^2=gf.$ Hence $gf:V \to V$ is a projection.

Show that $V_0:=ker(gf)$ and $V_1:= im(gf)$ have the desired properties.

Comment: Sorry what is $idw$?

Comment: $id_W$ denotes the identity map

Answer (score 1):

Just define $V_0,V_1$ as in 2 and 3, i.e. \begin{align*}
V_0&=\ker g\circ f = \{v\in V\mid g(f(v))=0\}\\
V_1&=\ker (g\circ f-id_V)=\{v\in V\mid g(f(v))=v\}
\end{align*}
Now check that these subspaces satisfy $V=V_0\oplus V_1$. Hint: $$v=v-g(f(v))+g(f(v))$$

Comment: What is $idV$ ?

Comment: @NuwanPriyankara it is the identity map on $V$, i.e. $V\to V$, $v\mapsto v$.

Comment: could you please tell me how to check the direct sum from this hint

Comment: Take $v\in V$ and show that $v-g(f(v))\in V_0$ and $g(f(v))\in V_1$. You will need the property $f\circ g = \operatorname{id}_W$ for this. For $V_0\cap V_1=0$ just look at the definitions of these subspaces.

Comment: Sorry, where does this statement come from $v=v-g(f(v))+g(f(v))$. How do we think it

Comment: If we take an arbitrary element $v$ in $V$ there is not much that we can do with it. Basically the only thing we have are the maps $f,g$. Since there is not much else we could do we look at the image $f(v)$ of $v$ under $f$. Now this is in the wrong space, so we apply $g$ again to get the element $g(f(v))\in V$. Now we check if this is in one of the subspaces $V_0,V_1$ and it turns out it is! The only thing left to do is look at the rest $v-g(f(v))$ and check that.

Comment: I understand what you said, but I totally lost on this question anyway thank you very much for your cooperation

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$g$ is bijective $W\to g(W)$ with inverse function $f|_{g(W)}:g(W)\to W$.